# $L^2$ integrability of a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, multiple-integral

I have to study the $L^2(\Omega)$ integrability ($\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded) of the function:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{(1+y^2)|x|^{1/3}} & x\neq 0\\
\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
**My attempt:**
Consider the following integral
$$
\iint_{\Omega}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(1+y^2)|x|^{1/3}}\bigg)^2dxdy
$$

we have that:

$$
\bigg|\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(1+y^2)|x|^{1/3}}\bigg)^2\bigg|\leq\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2/3}}
$$

Now $\Omega$ (being bounded) is contained in some square $[-R,R]\times[-R,R]$ and hence:

$$
\begin{split}
\iint_{\Omega}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{(1+y^2)|x|^{1/3}}\bigg)^2dxdy&\leq\iint_{\Omega}\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2/3}}dxdy\\
&\leq\int_{-R}^R\int_{-R}^R\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2/3}}dxdy\\
&=2R\int_{-R}^R\dfrac{1}{|x|^{2/3}}dx<\infty
\end{split}
$$
This proves that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$.

EDIT: I have also to check if $\partial_x f\in\mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)$; first of all we have that:
$$
\partial_x f=-\dfrac{\text{sgn(x)}}{3(1+y^2)|x|^{4/3}}
$$

Now if $\overline{\Omega}$ does not contain points with $x=0$ the function $\partial_x f\in\mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)$ being $|\partial_x f|^2$ continuous in $\Omega$ bounded. At this point I don't know how to proceed in the case on which points with $x=0$ are in the domain $\overline{\Omega}$. My idea is to consider $R$ small s.t. $[-R,R]\times[-R,R]\subset\overline{\Omega}$ and then:
$$
\iint_\Omega|\partial_x f|^2dxdy\geq\int_{-R}^R\int_{-R}^R\dfrac{1}{9(1+y^2)^2|x|^{8/3}}dxdy =\infty
$$
since the integral of $\frac{1}{|x|^{8/3}}$ diverges when $x=0$.

Is it fine?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Looks good. This is also true for unbounded $\Omega$, provided that $\Omega$ is contained in a strip $-R<x<R$ (you may need to adjust your proof for this).

Comment: I think that in the expression of the derivative of f, |x| has exponent 4/3...

Comment: @Aron you're right but the computation doesn't change

Comment: Yes you're right, the computation is still fine.